# Adding circle polygon to Map on click

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm looking to create an interactive map where a user can simply click to place various polygons/circles of varying size. Once they place these shapes, it would need to be saved so that the next time they visit the page it remembers where the user placed these polygons.

How can I use Mapbox to draw a circle like polygon on a map, of a predefined area/size, with a single click?

Comment: Please, mark the question as answer accepted if it solved your initial problem, this way will also help other users to know it was the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no `circles` in mapbox, any shape must be defined as a list of points to form a polygon... so **option 1** would be to create your own 'rounded' polygon as a *GeoJson* feature that you can use as source for a layer... here you have a sample

```
{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[-122.12994080132313,47.644482519898276],[-122.12990373140416,47.64449397672769],[-122.12986013420647,47.64449595450196],[-122.12982116483462,47.644490418558235],[-122.1297839964571,47.644476603480825],[-122.12975679969954,47.64445714476511],[-122.12973954095614,47.64443733202884],[-122.12973247670453,47.64440904091012],[-122.12973871662135,47.644379708121534],[-122.1297573021927,47.64435229906627],[-122.12978488013835,47.64433576206736],[-122.12980033418789,47.644325791349985],[-122.12985011085712,47.64431544969429],[-122.12989071574376,47.644316214791644],[-122.12993313243254,47.64432463813935],[-122.12996427964354,47.64434114057201],[-122.12998759690701,47.644364252993626],[-122.13000010533318,47.64438901705185],[-122.1300017490552,47.64441623463529],[-122.12999180010362,47.64444202406153],[-122.12997246871359,47.64446439674887],[-122.12994080132313,47.644482519898276]]],"type":"Polygon"},"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"circle"}}
```

You can try using https://studio.mapbox.com/datasets/ to understand how to draw this manually. That would enable to create some predefined 'almost perfect circles' and then allow the users to drag and drop them through the [Mapbox-gl-js draw](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/)

An **option 2** would be to create these shapes is to use [turf](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf) which is a geospatial js engine which allows you to create some predefined shapes, including [circles](http://turfjs.org/docs/#circle)

But if what you want is to just place the shape of a circle in a concrete point as a marker, that the users can drag and drop, **option 3** is in this sample fiddle I have created to show you [how to create a custom circle marker](https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/238d4o0w/6/), that consist in creating a marker based in an svg circle shape. Obviously this shape doesn't scale as a mapbox polygon vector based.

[image]

Just defining a style for the marker (image from wikipedia, you'll need to get your own svg shape)

```
<style>
.marker {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

and then the relevant js code

```
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'PUT YOUR TOKEN HERE';

    var geojson = {
      'type': 'FeatureCollection',
      'features': [{
          'type': 'Feature',
          'geometry': {
            'type': 'Point',
            'coordinates': [-77.032, 38.913]
          },
          'properties': {
            'title': 'Mapbox',
            'description': 'Washington, D.C.'
          }
        },
        {
          'type': 'Feature',
          'geometry': {
            'type': 'Point',
            'coordinates': [-122.414, 37.776]
          },
          'properties': {
            'title': 'Mapbox',
            'description': 'San Francisco, California'
          }
        }
      ]
    };

    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
      center: [-96, 15.8],
      zoom: 2
    });

    // add markers to map
    geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {
      // create a HTML element for each feature
      var el = document.createElement('div');
      el.className = 'marker';

      // make a marker for each feature and add it to the map
      new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
        .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
        .setPopup(
          new mapboxgl.Popup({
            offset: 25
          }) // add popups
          .setHTML(
            '<h3>' +
            marker.properties.title +
            '</h3><p>' +
            marker.properties.description +
            '</p>'
          )
        )
        .addTo(map);
    });
```

**EDITED**
I forgot an **option 4** to have circles on mapbox, in this case to paint circles but it would require some advanced coding to make them draggable. You can create a circles layer in this way...

https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/vjkt7wyx/14/